# Play Netflix videos using pyqt5

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, drm, widevine

I would like to run Netflix in a QWebengineView using pyqt5. However, streaming is not possible, because the "Widevine Content Decryption Module" is not found or does not work (error M7701-1003). Playback works for YouTube videos though. I would like to understand, why this happens and if it can be solved. Here is some code (you will need a Netflix account for testing):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    webEngineView = QWebEngineView()
    webEngineView.load(QUrl("https://www.netflix.com"))
    webEngineView.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is what I found out myself so far:
According to this [blog post](https://www.qt.io/blog/2016/06/03/netflix-qt-webengine-5-7), qt needs to be build with proprietary codecs enabled. This does not seem to be the case for pyqt5 by default. My original reasoning "YouTube videos work, so the proprietary codecs are enabled" is wrong.

An additional remark: I am using windows, according to [this resource (German)](https://praxistipps.chip.de/chromium-so-beheben-sie-netflix-probleme_50478), it is not possible to use widevine in chromium on windows. According to the [official docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwebengine-features.html) however, qt accepts a path to a windows dll.

So a possible solution would be to compile QT with proprietary codecs.

Comment: No, PyQt does not provide that feature by default. You have to compile Qt with that flag set, and then compile PyQt with that Qt.

Comment: Youtube mainly use the VP9 codec to provide videos, along with Opus audio and WebM container file format. Maybe(!) they use mp4 in specific platforms and browsers, but their main format is VP9/WebM since years now :)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP9

Comment: @Micha the problem is not only the audio/video stream but the DRM decryption that can only be achieved through Widevine, and Qt doesn't provide support for proprietary plugins like that by default, since they are third-party plugins that have licenses that are not compatible with the standard releases of Qt.

Comment: @musicamante sure, that's true. I just want to point out that the comparision to youtube doesn't make very much sense and the conclusion that webengine-proprietary-codecs are enabled based on the fact that youtube is working is non-sense, because youtube doesn't use proprietary codecs ;)

Comment: @Micha Sorry, my bad, now I get what you meant, I didn't understand that the "they" was referred to Youtube. The problem still stands though, as the A/V format could still be supported: according to [this](//netflixtechblog.com/more-efficient-mobile-encodes-for-netflix-downloads-625d7b082909), Netflix *also* supports VP9 (the link says it's used for downloaded content only, but it's also a 2016 post) and Ogg Vorbis is known to be among the supported audio formats. So, since the audio and video formats is decided based on the device, the main problem could still be on the Widevine plugin alone.